# Align to the right instead of the left

Tags: css

I have a unordered list that is a series of dots for a slider. How do I make it align to the right instead of the left, especially if the dots are removed or added?

Sometimes there might only be one

, sometimes there will be several.

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/redconservatory/ghDdm/

I put the word "link" in where there will be a dot....

Comment: it's not clear what you actually want

Comment: float them to the right instead of to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting your problem then below fiddle have your solution.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghDdm/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `float: left;` to `float: right;`

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood what you want but try the following:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ghDdm/4/

Answer (score 1):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/ghDdm/7/

.box floats to right, li floats to right

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are trying to accomplish here, but have you tried:

```
ul {
    float: right;
}
```

??